# pagination in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

I have a query with more than 3000 rows result set. I used an iterator to iterate each record. So I have to reduce the load of system and I suppose the best way is using the pagination in jsp. If anyone has a better idea I would be glad to hear it. something like fetch number or something like this.
The presentation technology is struts. 
If you think pagination is good please help me.

Comment: What's your concrete question?

Comment: In order to increase performance I would strongly suggest using pagination at the database level, if possible.

Comment: Take a look here: http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jsp/pagination-in-servlet-and-jsp/, this contains full example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paging the result set in jsp solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

Query database in with limit, I mean put limit in query, say `0 to 50` in first page. When request for first page then change your limit `0+(50*1) to 50+(50*1)` and for nth page it would be like `0+(50*n) to 50+(50*n)`

Comment: I don't know how to use pagination at database level?

Comment: to Quoi: How can I use limitation in my query? Does it return results in different pages?

Comment: you just have to improve your query. **SELECT** what is needed.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: to Russell Gutierrez: The query is correct; Imagine I have load all the unread emails but showing in separate pages to reduce Application server load

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is a good idea. However, you should remember that you **not only** need to make it work, but you have to understand the purpose as well.

Implement the pagination. But if you implement the pagination, but **still** fetches the same number of rows, your purpose is defeated. You should **improve your query** as well. You should fetch the **exact** number of rows for the **exact** number of entries to be displayed in a **single page in your pagination**. This way, both your application server and database server will gain the benefit of your implementation.

Comment: That can be true, but it can be wrong as well. The database query fetching the 3000 rows could be extremely fast, especially if the web server and the database are colocated, and the main performance problem could be due to the transfer of these 3000 rows over the internet, and the display of these 3000 rows by the browser.

Comment: @JBNizet that's why he should **query only what is needed**. if the pagination is 20 entries per page for example, with using a query such as `SELECT * from table where rownum > 1 and rownum < 21;` (for example) what will be transferred over the internet is only 20 rows. Likewise, displaying this minimum number of rows should not be a problem.

Comment: Imagine I have to load all emails, what should I do? I think the best way is pagination. Because I have to load all emails but show them in different pages.

Comment: You didn't understand what I meant. If the SQL query doesn't have any performance problem, but what is costly is the transfer of 3000 HTML rows over the internet, he could very well leave the database access code as is, and paginate in memory (i.e. generate a sublist of the list of rows retrieved from the database in the JSP). That's what the displaytag does by default, for example.

Comment: @JBNizet I ran the query in the database and it returned the result very quickly, but when it is going to show in jsp, consumes much time. I think not using of pagination caused the problem. Do you agree?